# Send a string containing http to socket

Tags: python, sockets

I have a strange behavior in the following code:

```
host = '127.0.0.1'  # listen to localhost
port = 8000
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.bind((host, port))
sock.listen(5)

while True:
    csock, caddr = sock.accept()
    if image:
        csock.send('www.google.com')
```

If I send get request in the browser, I will have 'www.google.com' displayed in the page. However, if I replace the text 'http://www.google.com', the page will not display anything at all.

How can I send 'http://www.google.com' and have it displayed as a string in the page?

Comment: csock.send('Content-Type: text/plain\n\nwww.google.com')

Comment: No. It will display the whole message with Content-Type and so on. I just want to display 'http://www.google.com'. Is it possible at all?